# How to resolve update issue in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

When i logged to my system I got the usual 49 updates pending, 18 are security updates so I ran `apt-get update` as root. The update ended with a message of Reading package lists...done. It didn't do any installs. I rebooted and logged in again to find the same message about updates again.
I tried deleting `var/lib/apt/lists` and recreating it and ran the apt-get update again but still the update stops with `Reading package lists...done.`

Any ideas on what could be the issue. Full disclosure: I recently played around with my cache for some reason using `sync` and `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. 
Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get update` only updates the indexes. You need to do `apt-get upgrade` to download and install updated packages.